# Corona SDK - iOS Game center score error, decimal comma

Tags: ios, lua, coronasdk, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I'm using https://github.com/GlitchGames/GGGameCentre library to publish score and to show leaderboard window.

The problem i have is that i'm pushing a score type "4.234" and at leaderboard window, my score changes to "0.042", i don't know why.

At itunes i have a configuration type "Score Format Type=Fixed Point - To 3 Decimals" and:

For english:
Fixed Point (10,000,012.218)

And for spanish:
Fixed Point (10,000,012.218)

Please, any help?

Comment: Thank you @Schollii, i know you're right, sorry, i'll do it better.

Comment: If you push a score of 123.456 what do you get when you pull it back in leaderboard window?

Comment: @SamHogan Just multiplay the score with 1000 and then submit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The score must be an integer even if you set up a Fixed Point - To 3 Decimals.

If you submit 1234 you would get 1.234

To fix you problem, just multiply your score with 1000 and then submit.